# Angular BehaviorSubject not sending next

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a service with a Behavior subject that does not seem to be sending on next().

I can see that the method gets fired when I console.log the response

```
errorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(
    {
        exception: false,
        message: '',
        segNum: ''
    }
);
error = this.errorSubject.asObservable();

responseHandler(response) {
    let obj = {};
    if (response.success) {
        return response.payload;
    } else {
        obj = {
            exception: true,
            message: response.exception.message,
            segNum: response.exception.seqNum
        };
    }
    console.log(obj);
    this.errorSubject.next(obj);
}
```

then when I subscribe to it like this:

```
error;
ngOnInit() {
    this.error = this.apiHandlerService.error.subscribe(obj => {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj.exception) {
            this.openModal();
        }
    });
}
```

so every API i call I make gets passed through this method. if no exception is returned it sends the payload, else it sends the exception to the error modal component.

When I trigger the else condition, it seems to be sending the initial value of the `errorSubject` and not getting the `next()`

Any ideas?

**After the answer below I tried rearranging my method so it returned last. still not working:**

```
responseHandler(response) {
    let obj;
    if (!response.success) {
        obj = {
            exception: true,
            message: response.exception.message,
            segNum: response.exception.seqNum
        };
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        obj = response.payload;
    }
    this.errorSubject.next(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Where is `responseHandler` invoked from?

Answer (score 1):

I have created stackblitz based on provided code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-3tvtrt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Here I invoke `responseHandler` method from component every 10 seconds and pass `response` manually, increasing `segNum` variable by one every time. Looks like it updates properly (you can see updated data in alert), so the `BehaviorSubject` works as expected. If your code is similar as provided part, the only thing I can think about is the response from server, so you have to check `Network` tab in developer tools and ensure, that you really get what you expect.

**EDIT 1**

The issue is in this part:

```
if (response.success) {
  return response.payload; // <- HERE
} else {
  ...
}
```

When you `return` anything, the function execution stops at that line and the below code of this function will not be executed. So in your case, when you get `response` with `success == true`, the function execution stops at the line `return response.payload`, and the interpreter doesn't reach the line `this.errorSubject.next(obj)`.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a newer version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-3tvtrt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Here I call `responseHandler` method with 2 different parameters by turn, and as expected, `alert` works fine and shows us the updated `seqNum` property. So you can see "EXCEPTION" in the console when we don't want to trigger our Behavior Subject, and "TRIGGER 'NEXT()'" when we want. Please, compare your code with my last provided example, it should work fine now. But you have to ensure, that `responseHandler` triggers itself when it's necessary, because other logic looks OK.

Comment: yea the strange thing is that in the `responseHandler` method, where I console.log the `obj` I have tested this against an actual API call where an error is returning. Ang it logs the correct response. properly. This seams to break down at where I hit the next(). its not sending the new object.

Comment: @SandraWillford, yeah, I see the issue... I have updated the answer, please check the "**EDIT**" block of my answer

Comment: I must have been looking at this too long, didn't catch that. so i need to reverse my conditional.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow, it's a deep night in my timezone. It will be much easier, if you will provide 2 examples of response (success and failure)

Comment: one example would look like this `{"success":true,"payload":{"doublePitchPrevention":7},"exception":null}` this would return the payload

Comment: and this one should trigger the Behavior subject `{"success":false,"payload":null,"exception":{"message":"Required long parameter 'userId' is not present","seqNum":630550}}`

Comment: @SandraWillford, I have updated the answer again, please, check out the last edit

Comment: I can see it working and have implemented it, but it still isn't working. There has to be something else going on. causing it to not send. The the problem is that the listening component is never getting the new value, so the new subject is never being sent.

Comment: @SandraWillford, sorry, I can't say more without live example, because in stackblitz which I provided, everything works fine. You have to add console logs and debug your real project

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: @SandraWillford, nice to hear that, sorry that didn't solve the whole problem, but I hope that pointed you to the right direction